# SQL Chinese formatting year part of a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using MS SQL Server 2016, I would like to retrieve only the year part of a given date and formatted using the Chinese culture code `zh`. This is simple to do with all other culture codes expect for Chinese culture codes. For example, to format a date to only show a year in the English (Ireland) culture I could do this:

```
select format(try_cast('2017-12-29' as date), 'yyy', 'en-IE')
```

The above will produce the desired output `2017`. However, this is not the case with the Chinese culture codes. For example,

```
select format(try_cast('2017-12-29' as date), 'yyy', 'zh')
```

The above produces `2017`. But the desired output is `2017年`. So, my question is how do I get this in the correct way? Below is how I am getting the desired output, but I am not sure if this is the correct way. Please assist.

```
select substring(format(try_cast('2017-12-29' as date), 'D', 'zh'), 0, 6)
```

Comment: Is the character at the end always `年` regardless of the year?

Comment: I would say yes @Larnu, the character `年` will always be at the end regardless of the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the character is always going to be `年` at the end, just concatenate it on:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(date,'20171229')),N'年');
```

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I was wondering why would I choose your solution over my solution I have outlined. Or why is your code better to use compared to my code? Thanks once again.

Comment: `FORMAT` is a pretty slow function, @HakunaN . For a scalar value, it's "fine", but start applying it to large datasets, and you often start to experience performance loses.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for answering my question. Very helpful.